# How to add extra field in my account page in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I want to add some extra fields including textfield,dropdown box in `customer/account/create/` page in magento.By default we have only login information and personal information with 2 to 3 textbox only.But I have to add billing details,destination type,billing address and so on.
Please refer this link below,it will help you to understand

https://www.webstaurantstore.com/myaccount.html?goto=register

```
I tried to solve this problem but unable to do that.If anyone knows this,please help me out.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add customer attributes to your database first.
Then you have to add them to your registration-template.
At last the attributes have be added to the customer fieldset in the config.xml

Here is a detailed step-by-step tutorial that may help you :-)
http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/custom-customer-signup-attributes